# Verifying equality

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I am trying to test equalities involving integrals. What are the possible causes for not being able to test the following:

```
q1 = Integrate[ a[x] + b[x], {x, 1, 2}];

q2 = Integrate[ a[x], {x, 1, 2}] + Integrate[ b[x], {x, 1, 2}];

FullSimplify[q1 - q2]
```

Running the above would not give me zero, and that's probably because Mathematica can't know even if the individual integral make sense on their own. But can I pass assumption that the functions are "well-behaved" and all individual interals exist, etc?

Answer (score 3):

Consider `a[x_] := Tan[x]; b[x_] := -Tan[x];`. Then obviously:

```
Integrate[a[x] + b[x], {x, 1, 2}] == Integrate[0, {x, 1, 2}] == 0
```

But neither of the component integrals converge. Thus, there exists at least one function for which the original result in the question does not necessarily hold:

```
Integrate[a[x] + b[x], {x, 1, 2}] ==
  Integrate[a[x], {x, 1, 2}] + Integrate[b[x], {x, 1, 2}] (* ??? *)
```

It also does not seem as though there's an easy way to make *Mathematica* assume that the integrals of `a[x]` and `b[x]` converge. Thus, like many odd cases where *Mathematica* seems hesitant to simplify something that looks simple, I assume that it's just trying to avoid unusual edge cases such as a convergent integral being divided into two non-convergent integrals.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `Integrate[]` to `D[]` then Mathematica is smart enough to know that differentiation is additive. This is not always true, though. Even if `f[x]` is not differentiable, then `f[x]-f[x]` is, so additivity does not always hold mathematically. Apparently, Mathematica is more cautious for integration by default. Similar cases are that Mathematica does not automatically transform `Log[x y]` to `Log[x]+Log[y]`. However, you can use `Rule[]` to enable such transformations if you really want to do it. The Swiss army knife of Mathematica is `Rule[]` and related functions.

Comment: I think Mathematica is trying to do the right thing here. I am just wondering if we can somehow pass the right assumptions, so that q1==q2 is True

Comment: You might as well use `q1 - q2 /. q1 -> q2` if you are going to make assumptions.